# How to update the SQL view if Master Table is getting bigger exponentially

Tags: sql

I have SQL view in which the master table is increasing exponentially. The view is having the aggregated data of the master table group by id.

Every day we drop the view and create the new so that we can visualize the view on the tableau.

Now since the data in the master table is increasing exponentially daily, the creating of view daily become a problem.

Suggest me a workaround

Need to focus on design part

```
drop view view_1
create view view_1 as

select a.*, c.lasttime
from
(
select id, 
max(time) as lasttime
from master_table
group by id
) as a
left join
(select t.id, t.lasttime, b.device 
from master_table as b
join(
select id, max(time) last_seen  from master_table group by id) as t
on b.id=t.id and b.time= t.lasttime
 ) as c
 on a.id = c.id and a.lasttime=c.lasttime
 order by lasttime desc;
```

Expected: Need to design the view so that I don't create to create the whole view everyday

Comment: I have no idea why you are recreating the view every day.  Nothing in the code changes.  I think I (at least) am missing what your real problem is.

Comment: Since the master table have the millions of record and its scanning every day to include the new data in aggregation

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a view is... A view is not a snapshot of the data. A view is just a stored query. The query you show is being run any time anyone looks at the view. There should be no need to update a view on a scheduled basis.